# SQL Server optimization query

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Does anyone know how to optimize this query? If I run this query and it takes more than 10 minutes to generate 11 rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT th.e_id,
                b_number,
                TQH.supplier_id AS VENDOR_ID,
                s.suppliername AS VENDOR_NAME,
                BUYER_POS,
                TQH.quotation_number AS QUOTATION_NO,
                TQH.contact_person AS CONTRACTOR_REP,
                TQD.tqd_currency_id AS CURRENCY_ID
FROM Tender_Header TH
INNER JOIN Tender_Quotation_Header TQH ON TH.e_id = TQH.e_id
INNER JOIN Tender_Quotation_Type TQT ON TQH.tqh_id = TQT.tqh_id
INNER JOIN Tender_Quotation_Detail TQD ON TQT.tqt_id = TQD.tqt_id
INNER JOIN EVPM.DBO.vwsupplier S ON TQH.supplier_id = S.supplierid
INNER JOIN Tender_Item TI ON TI.item_id = TQD.item_id
INNER JOIN Tender_Proposal TP ON tp.e_id = th.e_id
WHERE (TH.act_id = 46)
  AND (ISNULL(TQD.is_copied, '0') = '0')
  AND (tqd.tqd_result = 1
       OR tqh.resultpackage = 1)
  AND (b_number LIKE 'SM%'
       OR b_number_ref LIKE 'SM%')
  AND b_number NOT IN
    (SELECT eproc_id
     FROM newkimap.dbo.exp_mts_tender_main)
```

Comment: Paste it in SQL Management Studio, press Ctr+L to display the execution plan, and see if it suggests an index to add.

Comment: When you have the query open in Management Studio, enable 'Include Actual Execution Plan'(to the right on 'Execute') and Execute the query. Then paste the picture you get in here. That'll explain how the query is executed and what can be done to optimize it.

Comment: You can add your execution plan here for more information.OR You can use Analyse Query in Database tuning Advisor. However, be careful about what advises you take.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help you without knowledge about your database (tables, indexes).
You shoud consieder:

- change "not in " to "not exist"
  http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/
- you should have indexes on colum b_number and _b_number_ref

Marcin Pazgier